# JQuery on() method - combine event handlers

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to combine the following two event handlers that use the JQuery on() method?

```
$('#myform').on(
'click', '.delete_item',function(event){
        delete_item();
    }
);

$('#myform').on(
    'click', '.update_item',function(event){
        update_item();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#myform').on(
'click', '.delete_item',function(event){
        delete_item();
    }
).on(
    'click', '.update_item',function(event){
        update_item();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform').on('click', '.delete_item,.update_item', function(event) {
    (event.target.className == 'delete_item') ? delete_item() : update_item();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YWCnZ/)**

Comment: Is there actually any significant difference between your answer and Curt's?

Comment: Define significant? They both accomplish the task albeit in slightly different ways. The number of characters is nearly the same however mine only uses one call to .on() and everything is wrapped in one function.

Comment: OP obviously had a reason for combing these two selectors into one. And I assume it's not just to make it look prettier. So, I wonder whether or not your answer would have actually been better.​​​​​

Comment: @snuffn - Care to explain how my code doesn't accomplish what the OP wants?

Comment: What? It does work! I gave you the first upvote, because I thought it's better.

Comment: And like I said, he definitely had a reason why he wanted to combine these two selectors. And like you said, yours only uses ONE call to `.on()` and is wrapped in ONE `function()`.

Comment: @snuffn - oh, I thought you were wondering what the point of my example was.

Comment: @snuffn - and lol you're right, I didn't even see that the accepted answer only removed the characters `$('#myform')` once.

Comment: No, no. :) Sorry for the misunderstanding, tho.

Comment: Yup, that's why I was wondering why OP didn't accept your answer instead.